# How does entrypoint.sh file run in a Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I'm working with a debian base image that comes with an `entrypoint.sh` file stored in `/bin` by default.

If I don't define `ENTRYPOINT` in a Dockerfile, and I do a `docker run`, I see that `entrypoint.sh` runs automatically executing a bunch of commands.

If I define an `ENTRYPOINT` in a Dockerfile, and I do a `docker run`, I see that `entrypoint.sh` never runs and the command defined in `ENTRYPOINT` takes precedence.

My question is, what triggers `entrypoint.sh` to run? Is this a default behavior of docker?

Comment: Look at the containerfile of the base-image. I am quite sure that it either defines an `ENTRYPOINT`or a `CMD` referencing the `entrypoint.sh`.

Comment: @Turing85 good point, I did not think of that. I checked the base image Dockerfile and it does in fact run the `entrypoint.sh` file. It says `ENTRYPOINT ["tini",  "--", "/bin/entrypoint.sh"]` at the bottom.

Comment: There you have your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by referring to the base image. The ENTRYPOINT of the base image was running `entrypoint.sh`.